# How can I change label to span tag using Django filters

Tags: python, django, filter, tags

I am using django_filters to filter objects. My site displays filter fields with the following code:

```
<div class="inputBoxTEST">
    <label for="id_name__icontains">Name contains:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name__icontains" id="id_name__icontains">
    <label for="id_brand__icontains">Brand contains:</label>
      <input type="text" name="brand__icontains" id="id_brand__icontains">
    <label for="id_cloth_type">Type:</label> 
      <select name="cloth_type" class="form-control" id="id_cloth_type">
 </div>
```

django_filters generates inputs and labels.
I need to change label tag with span tag. How can i do that?

My code:
`views.py`

```
class WardrobeView(ListView):
    model = Clothes
    template_name = "wardrobe_TEST.html"
    context_object_name = "clothes"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["filter"] = ProductFilter(
            self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset()
        )
        return context
```

'filters.py`

```
import django_filters
from django import forms

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    cloth_type = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=ClothType.objects.all(),
        label='Type',
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Clothes
        fields = {
            'name': ['icontains'],
            'brand': ['icontains'],
        }
```

'wardrobe.html'

```
<div class="filter_form">
        <form method="GET">
            <div class="inputBoxTEST">
                {{ filter.form }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" style="--clr:#1644C9"><span>Submit</span><i></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
```